# Share "Search Folder" Parameters In Outlook 365 (not the contents of the searched folder)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365, search-folder

I am on a team that rotates the responsibility of parsing through a number of log results that are sent by e-mail.  We are using Office 365 e-mail and have individual work e-mail accounts as well as a pooled work account where these log files are sent to.  We all access both accounts using Outlook 2013.  In order to expedite this process, I've created search folders that search for certain types of logs so I can focus on each type of log in a particular order.

Is there anyway to export or share these search folder parameters with my co-workers? Or must search folders be "created" on each Outlook 2013 client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to share Search Folders. The only thing you can do is to give Full Access rights for mailbox containing these folders and add this mailbox to your co-workers Outlook profiles.

And there is no way export-import Search Folder settings as well.